# Помогите "красиво" расставить знаки

Tags: пунктуация

> Это, конечно, особое чувство – когда ты едешь в свой родной город, как
>   в чужой – исключительно по делу и останавливаешься в гостинице.

Мне мерещится, что

*– когда ты едешь в свой родной город, как в чужой –*

выглядит как вставка, которой не является. Боюсь, что сама налепила знаки при первом прочтении...

Как бы тут без потерь выкрутиться? Два тире - это перебор. Тогда и третье напрашивается...

Что можно поставить после "чужой"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы не хотите выделять "исключительно по делу"? Мне это сочетание видится именно как пояснение, я бы выделила:

Это, конечно, особое чувство – когда ты едешь в свой родной город как в чужой,  исключительно по делу, и останавливаешься в гостинице.

А вот "как в чужой" воспринимается как "в качестве", я бы не выделяла как сравнение: в родной едешь чужим.

Можно и вообще без лишних знаков:

Это, конечно, особое чувство, когда ты едешь в свой родной город как в чужой  исключительно по делу и останавливаешься в гостинице.Тогда подчёркивается единство придаточного предложения с однородными "едешь и останавливаешься".

Смотря какой смысл придаёте, что хотите подчеркнуть или ничего не подчёркивать.

Answer (score 2):

**Вариант со вставкой**

Это, конечно, особое чувство, когда ты едешь в свой родной город, как в чужой, – **исключительно по делу** – и останавливаешься в гостинице.

**Вставка всегда обособляется двумя тире, речь идет о выборе запятых**. Ставится запятая, закрывающая сравнительный оборот. Второй запятой (перед союзом И) нет, так как нет переноса запятой, относящейся к конструкции предложения: ты едешь.... и останавливаешся.

Answer (score 1):

Мне кажется, что можно подправить таким образом:

*Это, конечно, особое чувство, когда ты едешь в свой родной город, как в чужой – исключительно по делу - и останавливаешься в гостинице.*

Или вообще избавиться от тире:

*Это, конечно, особое чувство, когда ты едешь в свой родной город, как в чужой, исключительно по делу, и останавливаешься в гостинице.*

Есть еще варианты, мне они нравятся больше всего ( не знаю, правда, допустимо ли что-то менять в тексте? ):

*Это, конечно, особое чувство: [когда] ты едешь в свой родной город, как в чужой – исключительно по делу - и останавливаешься в гостинице.*

*Это, конечно, особое чувство: [когда] ты едешь в свой родной город, как в чужой, исключительно по делу, и останавливаешься в гостинице.*

Возможно, что-то подойдет?

Comment: Римма, спасибо, но "дело" от "гостиницы" отрывать нельзя: и то и другое - "в свой, как в чужой".